# How to change left panel programs with a script?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, gui, favorites

I have a desktop configuration scripts that I would like to expand with automation of left panel icons/programs shortcuts setup.

How can I modify this panel with a bash command?

[image: panel with programs I'm talking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favorite apps are stored in the dconf setting `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`. You could therefore define the icons that appear there as favorites with a command such as

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop']
```

Comment: sry, it took me so long to check it out. it works! thank you